# Android Studio 3.0.1 makes app laggy and slow

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio 3.0.1 makes my app laggy and slow!

I don't know why, but when I updated to version 3.0, and build my apps, they act laggy on opening activities especially if it is a list activity.

Comment: Run your app, then unplug the USB cable. If your app's performance improves, then the problem is tied to Android Studio monitoring (see, for example, [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68850784)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is not the Android Studio. It is the Android Profiler! When I enable it, my apps get slow even If I disconnect the wire. It looks Android Profiler attached something to the app sandbox that is laggy. Don't know how to fix it yet.

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue, and also looks related to the Android Profiler. Have you found any solution?

Comment: I noticed this when profiling a unity project in Android Studio. But I detached the device from computer, clear data and restart app. It's ok after that.

Comment: update your AS. you seem to be using a really old version! 3.1.2 is the most stable version!

Answer (score 1):

Since Instant Run doesn't work fine with some SDKs, it might be slowing your application down. Try turning off Instant Run for your project:

To disable this default setting:
Open the Settings or Preferences dialog: 
On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar. 
On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.

Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.

Uncheck the box next to Restart activity on code changes.